# MariaDB JDBC Sequential

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, sequential

I am trying to connect a MariaDB Galera multimaster cluster, consisted of 3 master nodes with an application using a JDBC connector. Unfortunately, for some reason, the MariaDB official website does not provide enough details when it comes to the sequential type of connector, I'm assuming it's because it is fairly new.

Can someone please confirm the syntax of the below command? or provide any relevant examples using a sequential MariaDB JDBC? Thanks in advance.

**jdbc:mariadb:sequential://host1:3306,host2:3306,host3:3306/my_db?autoReconnect=true&validConnectionTimeout=20&connectTimeout=25**

Does the above mean that if the first host is not available, then the second host will take a turn and so on? How about those additional parameters?

Failover mode is not ideal in this case as it is using a random picking connection initialization and I need a particular sequence to be followed. Same concept with replication mode, just based on master-slave replication.

Any details would help, thanks again.

Comment: What version of MariaDB Connector/J are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying, it's MariaDB Connector/Java 1.4.5.

Comment: Where is "sequential" mentioned?

Comment: Do you want `host1` to be preferentially picked?  If so, why?  Round-robin (or random) is often better.